# Creating controls using javascript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm currently working in a project in Laravel in which I have to create Radio Buttons for different diseases to specify Yes/No answers. Here I'm getting the disease names from the database which is passed from the controller.

I have created an php array just to have the names of the disease.

```
<?php $value=array();?>
@foreach($list as $disease)
<?php 
  $value[]=$disease->diseaseName; 
?>
@endforeach
```

**diseaseList.blade.php**

This is my design view. In this when the button is clicked a new radio button with disease name has to be created.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Patient ID &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<b style="font-size: 18px;">{{$id}} 
</b></label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="{{$id}}">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Patient Name &nbsp<b style="font-size: 18px;">{{$name}}</b></label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="patient_name" value="{{$name}}">
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">&nbsp<img 
style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="../../images/add_btn.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript for creating radio buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var values = new Array();
<?php foreach($value as $key => $val){ ?>
    values.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
<?php } ?>

var maxField = values.length; //Input fields increment limitation
var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
var x = 0; //Initial field counter is 1


var fieldHTML = '<div class="field_wrapper"><div class="label-group"><div 
class="line"></div><label style="font-weight: 900;" 
id="labelid">Disease</label></div><div class="form-check form-check-inline"> 
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Diabetes" 
id="inlineRadio1" value="Yes">&nbsp<label class="form-check-label" 
for="inlineRadio1">Yes</label></div><div class="form-check form-check- 
inline"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Diabetes" 
id="inlineRadio2" value="No">&nbsp<label class="form-check-label" 
for="inlineRadio2">No</label></div><div class="line"></div><div class="form- 
group" name="dName" value="dName"><input type="text" name="dName" id="dName" 
hidden size="5"><label name="dlabel" id="dlabel" hidden> mg/hg</label></div> 
</div>'; 

//Once add button is clicked
$(addButton).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x < maxField){ 
         var element=values[x];
         $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
         document.getElementById("labelid").innerText = element;
         x++; //Increment field counter
    }
});
});
```

Everything works fine. The problem is when I first click the button the radio button with name **Diabetes** created successfully and when the second time I press the button the previously created radio button **Diabetes** gets renamed to **Disease**(default name) and the new control with the second disease name **Hypertension** has been created.

[image: First Step Adding]

[image: Second Step Adding]

It is repeated for creating all the radio buttons. Please provide me a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make changes to HTML structure:

```
<div class="field_wrapper"></div>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">&nbsp<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="../../images/add_btn.png"></a>
</div>
```

So that the add button doesn't disappear on click.

In your script change the line:

```
$(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
```

To:

```
$(wrapper).prepend(fieldHTML); //Add field html
```

Here's the link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzbYyK?editors=1010

Comment: Glad to help! :)